# ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined

Tags: firebase, hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui

I was trying to connect **Firebase** into my android application .I used **Onsen UI framwork**.I got one error while running my app.

This is my error log->

```
05-22 09:31:30.071      763-763/io.cordova.hellocordova E/Web Console﹕ ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined
        at new <anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js:6:27)
        at invoke (file:///android_asset/www/lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js:3708:17)
        at Object.instantiate (file:///android_asset/www/lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js:3719:23)
        at file:///android_asset/www/lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js:6770:28
        at file:///android_asset/www/lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js:6183:34
        at forEach (file:///android_asset/www/lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js:310:20)
        at nodeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js:6170:11)
        at compositeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js:5634:15)
        at compositeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js:5637:13)
        at publicLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js:5539:30) at file:///android_asset/www/lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js:9400
```

This is my app.js->

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  var module = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);

  module.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
    var firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://sweltering-fire-7547.firebaseio.com/');
This is the code in app.js->
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(firebaseRef, function(error, user) {
    if (!error) {
        if (user) {
            $scope.username = user.email;
            myNavigator.pushPage('home.html', {
                animation: 'slide'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I added following lines in index.html->

```
<script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>                                                                   
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>                                                                           
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.17/firebase.js'></script>                      
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.1/firebase-simple-login.js'></script>
```

Comment: The code you've shown here for app.js won't ever be run. I don't think this provides an accurate [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is probably an ordering issue. The include for firebase lib is probably after your app.js is invoked, but that also can't be seen here.